# How to re-order a series of sublists?

Tags: python, list, sublist

How could I reorder the following sublist so that I could move the item at index 4 to index 0 across all sublists?

```
lsta = [['not','c','d','e','app','f'],['not','c','d','e','bear','f'],['not','c','d','e','cat','f']]

Desired_List= [['app','not','c','d','e','f'],['bear','not','c','d','e','f'],['cat','not','c','d','e','f']]
```

I'd like to move every index 4 in the original list to index 0? I can't use sort, because the item at index 4 can be an integer or a string

Comment: app is not in all. It's really about moving everything at index 4 to index 0 across all sublists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For handling the edit of moving every index 4 of the original list to index 0:

```
lsta = [['not','c','d','e','app','f'],['not','c','d','e','bear','f'],['not','c','d','e','cat','f']]
Desired_List = [lst[4:5]+lst[:4]+lst[5:] for lst in lsta]
```

Or if you don't need to keep the original version, you can just modify `lsta` in place using the following:

```
for lst in lsta:
    lst.insert(0, lst.pop(4))
```

Comment: Great solution on second part and I love that the second one is quick and efficient

Answer (score 2):

I believe the shortest form would be:

```
Desired_List= [[s[4]]+s[:4]+s[5:] for s in lsta]
```

Using `pop` and `insert` may be more efficient, depending on the size of your list